# Fitting data into the Self Organizing Map model using R

Tags: r, som

I'm new to R and its the first time i'm using SOM.
I want to predict survival using Self Organizing Map.

The following is the code i used to ingest data:

load raw data

```
train <- read.csv("train.csv", header = TRUE)
test <- read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Add a "Survived" variable to the test set to allow for combining data sets

```
test.survived <- data.frame(survived = rep("None", nrow(test)), test[,])
```

Combine data sets

```
data.combined <- rbind(train, test.survived)
```

Changed the variable to factors

```
data.combined$Survived <- as.factor(data.combined$survived)
data.combined$Pclass <- as.factor(data.combined$pclass)
```

Fitting the data to the SOM model

```
library(kohonen)
```

Train SOM

```
som.train.1 <- data.combined[1:891, c("pclass", "title")]
som.label <- as.factor(train$survived)

table(som.train.1)
table(som.label)
som.train.1.grid <- somgrid(xdim = 20, ydim=20, topo="hexagonal")

set.seed(1234)

som.model <- som(som.label, 
             grid=som.train.1.grid, 
             rlen = 100, 
             alpha = c(0.05, 0.01),
             keep.data = TRUE, 
             normalizeDataLayers = TRUE)

plot(som.model)
```

I get an error that says: sort.list(y): 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'

Comment: Can you provide the train and test data so that I can reconstruct your problem?